# How to get rid of lists inside of a list and only have numbers inside the list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to divide list of numbers into digits. For example: number 132 would divide to 1, 3 and 2. How can I get rid of the lists inside the list. So it's only integers.

```
lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
a = []
for digit in lst:
    a.append([int(i) for i in str(digit)])
print(a)
```

Output gives `[[1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [1, 0]]`.

Output that I expected `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 0]`.

Comment: Where is the list containing 132?

Comment: This is called list flattening. Search for it on StackExchange, there are many answers.

Comment: @Denziloe the list that the OP provided is not a nested list, so flattening is not required.

Comment: `a = [int(c) for i in lst for c in str(i)]`

Comment: You could change `a.append` to `a.extend(int(i) for i in str(digit))`

Comment: @Lifeiscomplex I don't think so, it seems to me that OP has almost reached the correct solution but needs as a final step to flatten the output list that they mentioned.

Comment: @Denziloe to me this looks like a standard list with int -- lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're adding a list to `a` here `a.append([int(i) for i in str(digit)])`, so you get a list of lists as a result. Instead you should add an int to get list of ints. Something like

```
lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
a = []
for num in lst:
    for digit in str(num):
        a.append(int(digit))
print(a)
```

Answer (score 1):

using list comprehension

```
lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
sol = [int(j) for i in lst for j in list(str(i))]
```

## output

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can give this a try:

```
In [56]: for item in lst:
    ...:     if item > 9: # this is what you're interested in
    ...:         for x in str(item):
    ...:             end.append(int(x))
    ...:     else:
    ...:         end.append(item)
    ...:
    ...:

In [57]: end
Out[57]: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 0]

In [58]: lst
Out[58]: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

The *fastest* thing I could think of was to convert the item to a string if it's higher than 9 and then iterate through that string and convert each *string-digit* back to int.